# Original paper of synchronous generator swing equation

Tags: rotational-dynamics, electromagnetic-induction, specific-reference

I found that the swing equation of a synchronous generator was developed by Andrey Andreyevich Andronov in 1926 in a paper titled "Theory of Electric Oscillations of Synchronous Machines". I've searched all of the repositories I know of, but I can't seem to find the original paper. I suppose the paper is in Russian, so I've tried to search for it like that, but without success. Does anyone know where can I find this paper?

Comment: [An archive of his work](https://isaran.ru/?q=ru/fund&ida=1&guid=56F795CE-1F43-6648-AF7C-F6C6D1118350) and the paper was possibly written later than 1926?